# How to extract subexpressions from String expression in Java?

Tags: java

If we assume a String expression `(x1(x2)(x3)(x4(x5(x6)(x7)))(x8))`, how to extract a substring (i.e., subexpression) of perticular depth?

If search item is x4, the subexpression is `(x4(x5(x6)(x7)))` or if search item is x5, the subexpression is `(x5(x6)(x7))`

Comment: I'd parse it, build a tree, and have a map point to each node by label... Then just get the subtree by the label, and there you are.

Comment: Are the subexpressions delimited by `()`?

Comment: I think you can use antlr. Hava a look at http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Grammars

Comment: Depending on the complexity of these strings, a (stripped down/modified) Lisp-Parser might be the most practical solution to this.

Answer (score 1):

[Demo on IDE-One](http://ideone.com/ChtLvj)

Here's what is probably a very naive solution, but without more detail about what you fully hope to achieve, this satisfies your question:

```
public static String getSubExpression(String expression, String search, char open, char close) {    
    int idx = expression.indexOf(open + search);

    if (idx == -1)
        return ""; //No match was found for the search term.

    int depth = 0;

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    //Loop over the rest of the string, looking for the terminating portion of the expression
    for (int i = idx; i < expression.length(); i++) {
        char c = expression.charAt(i);

        if (c == open) depth++; //If an open char is found, increment the depth.
        if (c == close) depth--; //If a close char is found, decrement the depth.

        builder.append(expression.charAt(i)); //append the character

        //when depth drops back to 0 or less, we know the entire expression has been parsed.
        if (depth < 1) break;
    }

    return builder.toString();
}
```

You'd use it as follows:

```
String expression = "(x1(x2)(x3)(x4(x5(x6)(x7)))(x8))";
System.out.println(getSubExpression(expression, "x1", '(', ')'));
System.out.println(getSubExpression(expression, "x2", '(', ')'));
System.out.println(getSubExpression(expression, "x3", '(', ')'));
System.out.println(getSubExpression(expression, "x4", '(', ')'));
System.out.println(getSubExpression(expression, "x5", '(', ')'));
System.out.println(getSubExpression(expression, "x6", '(', ')'));
System.out.println(getSubExpression(expression, "x7", '(', ')'));
System.out.println(getSubExpression(expression, "x8", '(', ')'));
```

#### Output

```
(x1(x2)(x3)(x4(x5(x6)(x7)))(x8))
(x2)
(x3)
(x4(x5(x6)(x7)))
(x5(x6)(x7))
(x6)
(x7)
(x8)
```

Comment: [We agreed that this is](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181774/stricter-kbd-usage-rules) [an abuse of the kbd-element](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176600/stricter-kbd-formatting-disallow-jsfiddle-links-and-other-non-kbd-content-fro?lq=1). So please stop doing it.

Comment: @Bobby Sure no problem, but drop the condescending tone as if everyone who frequents this site reads every article on meta.

Comment: In that case I may need to apologize, it does not really sound offensive to me. But that's maybe just me.

Comment: @Bobby Probably just misconstrued out of your attempt to be concise and brief. Your benign intention might be better conveyed by wording it `We discussed the use of the KBD element in this manner at meta, and found it to be an abuse of its intended purpose. We'd appreciate it if you didn't use it in this fashion in the future.` Wordier, but would receive a better response. That said, I also apologize for reading too much into your comment. Thanks for bringing this too my attention, as I never stopped to think about it being abuse until now, and was simply following others suit.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep it in mind next time I write an edit summary, and your example summary is actually pretty awesome, thanks for that. As background, there are many people on Meta which are trying *hard* to get formatting abuse into acceptable bounds (which would be zero, actually) and it's frustrating to see it creep up again and again (or those shortened URLs, my personal nemesis), it's kinda like fighting windmills. Anyway, your answer is a very good answer and we definitely need more of those!

Comment: @Bobby Agreed! I'll do my part to help in the battle. Thanks again for the information.

Answer (score 0):

```
    String source = "(x1(x2)(x3)(x4(x5(x6)(x7)))(x8))";
    String searchCriteria = "x4";

    // searching in the String assuming it is Mathematical expressions

    int searchCriteriaCount = searchCriteria.length();
    int firstMatchedCharIndex = 0;
    int lastMatchedCharIndex = 0;

    knowingIndex:
    for(int i = 0;i < source.length();i++){
        String currentSequence = source.substring(i, i+searchCriteriaCount);
        if(currentSequence.equals(searchCriteria)){
            firstMatchedCharIndex = i;
            break knowingIndex;
        }
    }

    char openingBracket = '(';
    char closingBracket = ')';
    int openingBracketsCount = 0;
    int closingBracketsCount = 0;

    char[] sourceChars = source.toCharArray();

    fullCriteria:
    for(int i = firstMatchedCharIndex-1;i<sourceChars.length;i++){
        if(sourceChars[i] == openingBracket){
            openingBracketsCount++;
        }

        if(sourceChars[i] == closingBracket){
            closingBracketsCount++;
        }

        if(openingBracketsCount == closingBracketsCount){
            lastMatchedCharIndex = i;
            break fullCriteria;
        }

    }

    String finalEquation = source.substring(firstMatchedCharIndex-1, lastMatchedCharIndex+1);

    System.out.println(finalEquation);
```

Comment: [Is there any benefit to allowing code-only answers while blocking code-only questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272/is-there-any-benefit-to-allowing-code-only-answers-while-blocking-code-only-ques)

Comment: @Bobby

:S i dont understand your point, the man asked for ideas, and this is one idea ... code only question is meaningless, because it doesnt ask any thing ... while code only answer is the "code" which answers the question

i myself benefit too much from codes in the answers, it's not my problem that you dont find it useful for you !!!!

Comment: Code only solutions, especially lengthy examples such as you have provided, do not work to edify the author of the question on why the code solves their problem. You could rectify this by adding some inline comments and/or breaking your code into blocks, and explaining each chunk's purpose. That is, if the chunks aren't completely self-explanatory within reason.